# Keystone coil vs leaf spring SMT AA battery holders

Tags: batteries

We have been using [Keystone 1024 SMT leaf-spring AA battery holders](http://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/Cylindrical-Cell-Holders/Holders-Plastic-PCB/p/404/id/1213/c_id/418) for a particular product:

[image]

We are thinking of changing to the newly released [coil-spring version](http://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/Cylindrical-Cell-Holders/Cylindrical-Cell-Holders-High-Performance-Coil-Spring/p/404/id/1213/c_id/1246):

[image]

The leaf-spring are initially very secure, holding the batteries in tightly, however after a while they lose their spring. Hopefully, the coil springs will have a better hold.

Has anyone had experience with the coil spring version and can comment on whether they hold the battery more securely?

Comment: I don't have experience with the specific battery holders you are talking about. But the resistance of the coil springs in general can be fairly high. If your application uses high currents at all, you might want to reconsider. But if not, then coils may be fine. With leaf-spring types, if the proper material is chosen, and if travel is limited, they do not become permanently compressed. But I guess you have to chose from the available options.

Comment: @mkeith thanks for your experiences. Max current is short bursts of 100mA to write to a uSD card but usually it is around 0.015mA. Currently the coil spring version is out of stock so that might solve the problem for me anyway. :P

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you keep use the leaf-spring version, or choose the version which spring shape like a trangle, and bent a bar at center of the touch end.

[image]

the problem is the straight coil spring at same diameter is easy to tilt, i had some trouble years ago one of the spring coil end touched the slot between the negative and positive of battery and shorted it. i forgot which type of battery i use(this wolden't happen for good protected battery.)

the leaf-spring and trangle coil spring will always keep touch the center